# Why cant I have 2 iframes side by side with total width 100%?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have total 4 `iframe`.

```
<body>
    <iframe id="top_frame" src=""></iframe>
    <iframe id="left_frame" src=""></iframe>
    <iframe id="right_frame" src=""></iframe>
    <iframe id="bottom_frame" src=""></iframe>
</body>
```

I want 2 of them `left_frame` and `right_frame` side by side with their total width 100% (25% for `left_frame` and 75% for `right_frame`).

So I put this CSS:

```
#top_frame {
    width: 100%;
}
#left_frame {
    width: 25%;
}
#right_frame {
    width: 75%;
}
#bottom_frame {
    width: 100%;
}
```

But it did not work as you can see in this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/srhcan/mwg3j17d/1/

If I decrease the width of `right_frame` to 73% then they will show side by side but will leave bit space on the right side.

What is the reason of this?

How can I have 2 iframes side by side with total width 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to tell the `#left_frame` and `#right_frame` that you want them to be next to each other.

You can do this a few different ways, but one of the most popular is floating them:

```
#left_frame,
#right_frame {
    float: left;
}
```

Now, this works, but you still won't see them next to each other.
That's because they have an inherent 2px border by default.

Therefore, you can either remove the border:

```
#left_frame,
#right_frame {
    float: left;
    border: none;
}
```

OR, you can subtract the border from the widths. I would recommend this.

```
#left_frame,
#right_frame {
    float: left;
}

#left_frame {
    width: calc(25% - 4px);
}

#right_frame {
    width: calc(75% - 4px);
}
```

Link to your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwg3j17d/4/

EDIT - As pointed out by @Rob Scott, you can add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the iframes to not have to use the `calc` statements. That would look like:

```
#left_frame,
#right_frame {
    float: left;
}

iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Updated fiddle to fix the spacing issue to the right of `right_frame`
http://jsfiddle.net/mwg3j17d/12/

Comment: or just use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: @RobScott True! He could do that as well to not have to use the calc statements.

Comment: @AlexWright @RobScott thanks for your answer but I can see there is some space left on the right of the `right_frame` i.e. the right border of the `right_frame` is not aligned with the right border of `top_frame` and `bottom_frame`. It means that the total width of `left_frame` + `right_frame` is still not 100%. Why?

Comment: @srh If you use the method I posted above that @RobScott recommended, you will not have any space left to the right of the `right_frame`. The space is caused by the default spacing of the border widths.

Comment: @srh I included a link to an updated fiddle that uses the box-sizing to fix the spacing issue.

Comment: @AlexWright thanks. Question: why you have `float: left;` defined for both `left_frame` and `right_frame`?

Comment: @srh So that `left_frame` and `right_frame` will be next to each other as opposed to being stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Your iframes have a 2px border on them by default which is not included in the width of the box. You can remove this border with css using `border: 0px`, or include it in the width calculation using `box-sizing: border-box;' as Rob Scott mentioned. This will allow you to have their widths add to 100%. can place them side by side, by floating one left.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/mwg3j17d/13/)**

CSS:

```
#top_frame {
    width: 100%;
}
#left_frame {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
#right_frame {
    width: 75%;
}
#bottom_frame {
    width: 100%;
}
iframe {    
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I can see there is some space left on the right of the `right_frame` i.e. the right border of the `right_frame` is not aligned with the right border of `top_frame` and `bottom_frame`. It means that the total width of `left_frame` + `right_frame` is still not 100%. Why?

Comment: the top frame and bottom frame were set to display their content at 100% not including borders. I updated my example to set all iFrames to include the border in their width calculations. Now they add up to 100%.

Comment: See the box-sizing properties. The default is content only. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 1):

To answer your actual question of *why*:

Even without the borders, you still have a space between the two iframes.  25% + 75% + four borders + the size of the space is going to be more than 100%, so the second one has to wrap to a new line.

The simplest way to do this nowadays, and the way least likely to wreak havoc or fall apart on you, is to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), which is a pretty flexible way of stuffing some number of boxes in a row or column:

http://jsfiddle.net/mwg3j17d/10/

```
<iframe id="top_frame" src=""></iframe>
<div id="middle-row">
    <iframe id="left_frame" src=""></iframe>
    <iframe id="right_frame" src=""></iframe>
</div>
<iframe id="bottom_frame" src=""></iframe>
```

```
iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#middle-row {
    display: flex;
}
```

Browser support is pretty good, though it's not gonna work on IE6.

Comment: it works. In your JSFiddle you are using `justify-content: space-between;` for `#middle-row` What is that for? I don't see any change if I remove it.

Comment: sort of force of habit.  `justify-content` says what to do with any space left over; the default is to clump everything together in the middle, but `space-between` will spread the space out evenly between all the items.

Answer (score 0):

A few changes to your HTML and CSS will allow you to do this by using table `display` styles with some divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/mwg3j17d/6/

```
<body>
    <iframe id="top_frame" src=""></iframe>
    <div class="cols">
        <div class="col-left">
            <iframe id="left_frame" src=""></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right">
            <iframe id="right_frame" src=""></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="bottom_frame" src=""></iframe>
</body>
```

---

```
#top_frame {
    width: 100%;
}
#left_frame {
    width: 100%;
}
#right_frame {
    width: 100%;
}
#bottom_frame {
    width: 100%;
}

.cols {
    display: table-row;
}

.col-left, .col-right {
    display: table-cell;
}

.col-left {
     width: 25%;   
}

.col-right {
     width: 75%;   
}
```

You could also do it with a table itself.