# How can I make two iframes fit the width of the page?

Tags: html, css, iframe, width

My issue is that I have two iframes on the page, one for a persistent side menu and one for main body content. I want the side menu to take up roughly 12% of the screen (just personal choice) and then the content to fit the rest of the page width. I've seen many solutions for fitting a single iframe onto a page but I cannot find anything to help my specific issue exactly.

I tried setting the `bodyContent` iframe's width to 88% so that 88 + 12 = 100, but this makes the iframe appear below the `menu` iframe. I guess 100% is too wide for the page in this case...? My rudimentary solution was to set the width of `bodyContent` to the 87.6% (87.7% was too much) so that it just fits the full width of the page with a tiny sliver of white along the right border.

I know there must be a more simple solution to this problem so that the two iframe's can cleanly fit the full width of the page. How could I go about doing so?

Here's what I have right now (the iframe's sources are .aspx files which I have hidden):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Foo</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />      

        <style>
            .menu {
                float: left;
                width: 12%;
            }
            .bodyContent {
                float: left;
                width: 87.6%;
                border: none;
            }
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            div#root {
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            div#root > iframe {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>      
    </head>     

    <body>
        <div id="root">
            <iframe class="menu" src="hidden"></iframe>
            <iframe class="bodyContent" src="hidden"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't forget that width doesn't include margins. e.g. your frames may be 88%+10px because they have 5px margins, making the total width 88%+12% + 20px = 100% + 20px - wider than the available space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iFrame width does not include the border by default. Your border is 2px wide by default. To include it, add the `box-sizing: border-box;` css style to include the border in your iframe width.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/7hwrxyb1/)

```
iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box; /*include borders in the width calculation */
}
.menu {
    float: left;
    width: 12%;
}
.bodyContent {
    float: left;
    width: 88%; /*width can now be 88%*/
    /*border: none; removed so you can see the iframe in this example*/
}
```

[Here is a similar Question and Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520211/why-cant-i-have-2-iframes-side-by-side-with-total-width-100/30520332#30520332)

Answer (score 1):

```
div#root > iframe {
       height: 100%;
       float:left;
       box-sizing:border-box;
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2co8yrs/2/